# Read txt file to pandas dataframe with unique delimiter and end of line

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file of a table, with a unique delimiter and a unique set of characters to mark the end of each line / row.

e.g.
new column marked by `#%#`
new row marked by `##@##`

So the text file might read...

```
cat#%#dog#%#rat#%#cow##@##red#%#blue#%#green#%#yellow##@##north#%#south#%#east#%#west
```

Which should be read as a table with 3 rows and 4 columns, where I can add column names during loading.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat | dog | rat | cow |
| red | blue | green | yellow |
| north | south | east | west |

I've tried `pd.read_csv(file_name.txt,  delimiter="#*#", lineterminator = '##@##')` with engine as both python and c, but c can't accept more than one character for the delimiter and python can't accept values for delimiter and lineterminator.

Is my only option to read the text file, change the delimiter and end of line value to a single character, save and read again using read_csv?

Comment: The example you gave has most of the column separators as '##' and only the last one as '#*#'. Can you please check which one is correct and edit accordingly?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The stack markdown removed the * when I published. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess as pointed out by matheubv there is no option to solve this with `pd.read_csv`. However this can be easily fixed a few lines of codes. Just open the file (in the example `sample.csv`) and parse it (use the string method `.replace()`). Afterwards you can read in the data currently saved as string in `data_string` with a very basic list comprehension.

Hope this work-around helps you

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("Data/sample.csv")

with p.open() as f:
    string_data = f.readline().replace('#%#',';').replace('##@##','\n')
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in string_data.split('\n')])
    print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
       0      1      2       3
0    cat    dog    rat     cow
1    red   blue  green  yellow
2  north  south   east    west
```

Comment: I have a number of txt files in a folder, some are pipe delimiter and others are in the format above. Is there an efficient way to check the delimiter format and then read the file appropriately? Or do I do as above, read, check if the string contains either | or the format above and then populate the dataframe appropriately?

Comment: You can allways expand my example provided and use [string methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp) e.g. `.find()` and an if-condition to see which delimitor is used. However give it a try yourself if you run into problems try to search, e.g., stackoverflow for a solution first (as there are a lot of topics on string methods). When you cant find the right answer just open a new Question

Comment: Will do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation

> lineterminator : str (length 1), optional
> Character to break file into lines. Only valid with C parser.

Therefore I think your best option would be to open the text file and replace the line terminator before using read_csv.